# CKEditor add a button to change the text area background colour

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have a Ruby on Rails application that contains CKEditor to allow a user to style text on a form. I have this so that a user can change the styling of text in an email.

Is it possible to add a further button to the toolbar that allows the user to select the background colour of the email?

Comment: I was going to post a very similar question i wanted to put h1 style info whenever a heading 1 was selected and div background style when a div was opened. yours is pretty similar to mine

Comment: @muratkh if that's the case, then feel free to vote up the question! :)

Comment: true that......